# Issue with simple md5 login script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, md5

I'm trying to get my login script to work. It uses random salt & md5. At present just typing a valid username and pressing submit without a password authenticates the user. (**I know md5 isn't safe, will be moving to brcrypt later but need to get this working first**)

Just cant see the error - any help much appreciated.

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $user = isset($_POST['username']) ? $G['db']->escape($_POST['username']) : "";
    $pass = isset($_POST['password']) ? md5($G['db']->escape($_POST['password'])) : "";

    $account = $G['db']->queryUniqueValue("SELECT username,salt,password,uid FROM `".$C['db']['table']."` WHERE `username` = '$user'");

    //User exists
    if($G['db']->numRows()==1) {
      //If the password is right
      if(md5($account['salt'].":".md5($pass))) {
        //Validate the user
        $G['login']->validateUser(array("username"=>$account['username'], "id"=>$account['uid'], "utype"=>$account['utype']));

        //User Validated redirect them
        header("Location: ./?e=validpage");

      } else {
```

Comment: "I know md5 isn't safe" --- o_O It is "not safe" for advanced developers, your code passes user without password at all

Comment: Salted md5 is plenty safe...  `md5(md5(md5($salt).md5($salt.md5($password)).md5($salt)))`  No one could ever get to that.  srsly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(md5($account['salt'].":".md5($pass)))
```

Well... This creates an MD5 hash of the salt in the database and the entered password. And compares it to... `true`. And any non-empty string is `true`. So this condition reads *if the entered password together with the salt hashes to any non empty string* (which it will every time), *let the user in*.

You probably meant to do something like:

```
if (md5($account['salt'] . ':' . md5($pass)) === $account['password'])
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```